# Unit tests on Caffeine LoadingCache implementation pass individually but one fails when run together

Tags: java, caching, junit, mockito, caffeine

The unit tests (JUnit, Mockito) that I've written for my Caffeine CacheLoader implementation all succeed when I run them individually, but one of them fails when I run them all together. I believe that I am following best practices in using `@Before` for all of my test object setups.

When run with the others, the test *testGet_WhenCalledASecondAndThirdTimeBeyondCacheDuration_LoadingMethodCalledASecondTime* fails every time with the following error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.verification.TooLittleActualInvocations: 
testDataSource.getObjectWithKey(
    "mountain-bikes"
);
Wanted 2 times:
-> at ErrorHandlingLoadingCacheFactoryTest.testGet_WhenCalledASecondAndThirdTimeBeyondCacheDuration_LoadingMethodCalledASecondTime(ErrorHandlingLoadingCacheFactoryTest.java:67)
But was 1 time:
-> at ErrorHandlingCacheLoader.load(ErrorHandlingCacheLoader.java:41)
```

Something would appear to be carrying over between the tests, but given what I am doing in my `@Before` method I'm not sure how that could be. I've tried calling the following in an `@After` method:

- `invalidateAll()`
- `cleanUp()`
- `Mockito.reset(testDataSource)`

I have also tried to manually pass a `singleThreadExecutor` to the cache builder, and waiting for it to finish whatever it is doing in `@After` in case that has anything to do with it.

My Caffeine CacheLoader implementation just overrides the `reload` method to return the currently cached value if the attempt to refresh it fails (throws an exception). Other than that, its pretty vanilla.

```java
@Component
public class ErrorHandlingLoadingCacheFactory {

    private final Ticker ticker;

    @Autowired
    public ErrorHandlingLoadingCacheFactory(Ticker ticker) {
        this.ticker = ticker;
    }

    public <T> LoadingCache<String, T> buildCache(String cacheName,
                                                        long duration,
                                                        TimeUnit timeUnit,
                                                        Function<String, T> valueResolver) {
        return Caffeine.newBuilder()
                .refreshAfterWrite(duration, timeUnit)
                .ticker(ticker)
                .build(new ErrorHandlingCacheLoader<>(cacheName, valueResolver));
    }
}
```

```java
/**
 *  a LoadingCache that retains stale cache values if
 *  an attempt to retrieve a fresh value for a given key fails.
 *
 * @param <K> the cache key type
 * @param <V> the cache value type
 */
class ErrorHandlingCacheLoader<K, V> implements CacheLoader<K, V> {
    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ErrorHandlingCacheLoader.class);

    private final String cacheName;
    private final Function<K, V> valueResolver;

    /**
     * Create a cache.
     *
     * @param cacheName the cache name
     * @param valueResolver the method used to get a value for a key
     */
    public ErrorHandlingCacheLoader(String cacheName, Function<K, V> valueResolver) {
        this.cacheName = cacheName;
        this.valueResolver = valueResolver;
    }

    /**
     * Load the initial cache value for a given key.
     * @param key the cache key
     * @return the initial value to cache
     */
    @Override
    public V load(@NonNull K key) {
        return valueResolver.apply(key);
    }

    /**
     * Attempt to reload a value for a given key.
     * @param key the cache key
     * @param oldValue the currently cached value for the given key
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public V reload(@NonNull K key, V oldValue) {
        V value = oldValue;
        try {
            value = valueResolver.apply(key);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            logger.warn("Failed to retrieve value for key '{}' in cache '{}'. Returning currently cached value '{}'.", key, cacheName, oldValue);
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

```java
public class ErrorHandlingLoadingCacheFactoryTest {

    private ErrorHandlingLoadingCacheFactory errorHandlingLoadingCacheFactory;

    private FakeTicker fakeTicker;
    private TestDataSource testDataSource;

    private LoadingCache<String, TestObject> loadingCache;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        fakeTicker = new FakeTicker();
        testDataSource = mock(TestDataSource.class);
        errorHandlingLoadingCacheFactory = new ErrorHandlingLoadingCacheFactory(fakeTicker::read);
        loadingCache = errorHandlingLoadingCacheFactory.buildCache("testCache", 1, TimeUnit.HOURS, testDataSource::getObjectWithKey);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        validateMockitoUsage();
    }

    @Test
    public void testGet_WhenCalledTwiceWithinCachePeriod_LoadingMethodCalledOnce() {
        // Arrange
        TestObject testObject = new TestObject("Mountain Bikes");
        when(testDataSource.getObjectWithKey("mountain-bikes")).thenReturn(testObject);

        // Act
        TestObject result1 = loadingCache.get("mountain-bikes");
        TestObject result2 = loadingCache.get("mountain-bikes");

        // Assert
        verify(testDataSource, times(1)).getObjectWithKey("mountain-bikes");
        assertThat(result1).isEqualTo(testObject);
        assertThat(result2).isEqualTo(testObject);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGet_WhenCalledASecondAndThirdTimeBeyondCacheDuration_LoadingMethodCalledASecondTime() {
        // Arrange
        TestObject testObject1 = new TestObject("Mountain Bikes 1");
        TestObject testObject2 = new TestObject("Mountain Bikes 2");
        when(testDataSource.getObjectWithKey("mountain-bikes")).thenReturn(testObject1, testObject2);

        // Act
        TestObject result1 = loadingCache.get("mountain-bikes");
        fakeTicker.advance(2, TimeUnit.HOURS);
        TestObject result2 = loadingCache.get("mountain-bikes");
        TestObject result3 = loadingCache.get("mountain-bikes");

        // Assert
        verify(testDataSource, times(2)).getObjectWithKey("mountain-bikes");
        assertThat(result1).isEqualTo(testObject1);
        assertThat(result2).isEqualTo(testObject1);
        assertThat(result3).isEqualTo(testObject2);
    }

    @Test(expected = RuntimeException.class)
    public void testGet_WhenFirstLoadCallThrowsRuntimeException_ThrowsRuntimeException() {
        // Arrange
        when(testDataSource.getObjectWithKey("mountain-bikes")).thenThrow(new RuntimeException());

        // Act
        loadingCache.get("mountain-bikes");
    }

    @Test
    public void testGet_WhenFirstLoadCallSuccessfulButSecondThrowsRuntimeException_ReturnsCachedValueFromFirstCall() {
        // Arrange
        TestObject testObject1 = new TestObject("Mountain Bikes 1");
        when(testDataSource.getObjectWithKey("mountain-bikes")).thenReturn(testObject1).thenThrow(new RuntimeException());

        // Act
        TestObject result1 = loadingCache.get("mountain-bikes");
        fakeTicker.advance(2, TimeUnit.HOURS);
        TestObject result2 = loadingCache.get("mountain-bikes");

        // Assert
        verify(testDataSource, times(2)).getObjectWithKey("mountain-bikes");
        assertThat(result1).isEqualTo(testObject1);
        assertThat(result2).isEqualTo(testObject1);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGet_WhenFirstLoadCallSuccessfulButSecondThrowsRuntimeException_SubsequentGetsReturnCachedValueFromFirstCall() {
        // Arrange
        TestObject testObject1 = new TestObject("Mountain Bikes 1");
        when(testDataSource.getObjectWithKey("mountain-bikes")).thenReturn(testObject1).thenThrow(new RuntimeException());

        // Act
        TestObject result1 = loadingCache.get("mountain-bikes");
        fakeTicker.advance(2, TimeUnit.HOURS);
        TestObject result2 = loadingCache.get("mountain-bikes");
        TestObject result3 = loadingCache.get("mountain-bikes");

        // Assert
        verify(testDataSource, times(2)).getObjectWithKey("mountain-bikes");
        assertThat(result1).isEqualTo(testObject1);
        assertThat(result2).isEqualTo(testObject1);
        assertThat(result3).isEqualTo(testObject1);
    }

    @Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
    public void testGet_WhenKeyIsNull_ThrowsNullPointerException() {
        // Arrange
        String key = null;

        // Act
        loadingCache.get(key);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGet_WhenFirstLoadCallReturnsNull_DoesNotCacheResult() {
        // Arrange
        TestObject testObject1 = new TestObject("Mountain Bikes 1");
        when(testDataSource.getObjectWithKey("mountain-bikes")).thenReturn(null).thenReturn(testObject1);

        // Act
        TestObject result1 = loadingCache.get("mountain-bikes");
        TestObject result2 = loadingCache.get("mountain-bikes");

        // Assert
        verify(testDataSource, times(2)).getObjectWithKey("mountain-bikes");
        assertThat(result1).isEqualTo(null);
        assertThat(result2).isEqualTo(testObject1);
    }

    @Data
    class TestObject {
        private String id;
        public TestObject(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    }

    interface TestDataSource {
        TestObject getObjectWithKey(String key);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe use a random name for each cache instead of "testCache"? A Junit `Rule` will expose the test-name or you could just increment a static counter.

Comment: Can you try using `Caffeine.executor(Runnable::run)`? That should be similar to your use of a single-threaded executor, but disables all asynchronous activity by the cache (in case there is a surprising race between your tests).

Comment: @BenManes that did the trick! If you want to write an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Oh no thanks, its cheating when I wrote the code! Like getting credit for fixing my own bugs =) You can answer it. In the single-thread case, you probably forgot to use `awaitTermination` for it to coalesce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ben Manes suggested in his comment that I use `Runnable::run` as the LoadingCache's executor when running unit tests, which did the trick!

I implemented a second protected `buildCache` method on my factory that additionally takes an `Executor` parameter, which my test class uses to pass `Runnable::run`.

The updated *ErrorHandlingLoadingCacheFactory*:

```java
public class ErrorHandlingLoadingCacheFactory {

    private final Ticker ticker;

    @Autowired
    public ErrorHandlingLoadingCacheFactory(Ticker ticker) {
        this.ticker = ticker;
    }

    /**
     * Create an in-memory LoadingCache
     *
     * @param cacheName the name of the cache
     * @param duration how long to keep values in the cache before attempting to refresh them
     * @param timeUnit the unit of time of the given duration
     * @param valueResolver the method to call to get a value to load into the cache for a given key
     * @param <T> the type of object to store into the cache
     * @return the newly created cache
     */
    public <T> LoadingCache<String, T> buildCache(String cacheName,
                                                        long duration,
                                                        TimeUnit timeUnit,
                                                        Function<String, T> valueResolver) {
        return buildCache(cacheName, duration, timeUnit, valueResolver, ForkJoinPool.commonPool());
    }

    /**
     * Create an in-memory LoadingCache
     *
     * @param cacheName the name of the cache
     * @param duration how long to keep values in the cache before attempting to refresh them
     * @param timeUnit the unit of time of the given duration
     * @param valueResolver the method to call to get a value to load into the cache for a given key
     * @param executor the executor for the cache to use
     * @param <T> the type of object to store into the cache
     * @return the newly created cache
     */
    protected <T> LoadingCache<String, T> buildCache(String cacheName,
                                                     long duration,
                                                     TimeUnit timeUnit,
                                                     Function<String, T> valueResolver,
                                                     Executor executor) {
        return Caffeine.newBuilder()
                .refreshAfterWrite(duration, timeUnit)
                .ticker(ticker)
                .executor(executor)
                .build(new ErrorHandlingCacheLoader<>(cacheName, valueResolver));
    }
}
```

the updated `setUp()` method in *ErrorHandlingLoadingCacheFactoryTest*:

```java
...
@Before
    public void setUp() {
        fakeTicker = new FakeTicker();
        testDataSource = mock(TestDataSource.class);
        errorHandlingLoadingCacheFactory = new ErrorHandlingLoadingCacheFactory(fakeTicker::read);
        loadingCache = errorHandlingLoadingCacheFactory.buildCache("testCache", 1, TimeUnit.HOURS, testDataSource::getObjectWithKey, Runnable::run);
    }
...
```

There must have been a race between my tests that my single-threaded executor didn't catch, probably because I didn't properly wait for it to terminate in my `@After` method. Ben suggested that if I used `awaitTermination` on the single-threaded executor, that might also have worked.